# Sorting options for new answers aren't rendered

Tags: bug, status-deferred, answers, live-refresh

I opened the page of a question with no answers. Some time later there were answers to the question and the page prompted with `2 new answers`.

I clicked it and the answers appeared on the page. However, the control block with options of sorting the answers failed to appear:

[image]

I observed the behavior on Workplace, but I'm sure its the same on all StackExchange sites.

Comment: I wanted to say that it might be related to randomized answers order for new answers (related to prevent [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)), but I'm not sure... or I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Andrew T., In the case I observed, the oldest answer was the first. But this is just one case.

Comment: @Geoff any details besides the dreaded "deferred"? (which from what I've seen, very rarely becomes planned or completed)